# Display particular signed contract in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to implement DocuSign (API) in my web application having following requirements.

1. User should be able to sign a document from our application(web application): (this functionality working as expected)
2. Next process is (admin) should be able to view particular document along with signed by the user. (from our application)

I am using this API `accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}` it gives me PDF response but when I tried to download pdf it nothing display except original document. (we need along with signed)

Apart from this, I tried to open a file using URL which was created during signing ceremony still no luck it's doesn't work after getting signed by the user. (It's getting expired over a time)

So, my question is how we can view a particular document (signed document) within our application?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have correct envelope that is in "Completed" status.
If you make a GET call to `accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/` you should get a list of all documents in this envelopes, which should include the completed documents as well and you should be able to download them.